# Не вызывается MouseLeftButtonDown

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-шаблоны, wpf-стили

Метод присвоенный обработчику события MouseLeftButtonDown  не вызывается.

//App

```
<Style x:Key="SeriousStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Name="AAA">
 <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"  >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                      Duration="0:0:0.6"   RepeatBehavior="0:0:3">
               <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Lime" KeyTime="00:00:0" />
                   <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="00:00:0.3" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger> 
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnFirst" Content="Bla"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,189,0,0"    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="223" Height="79"  MouseLeftButtonDown="AnswerWasChosen" Style="{DynamicResource SeriousStyle }" >

    </Button>
```

Comment: А _без_ стиля проблема не воспроизводится?

Comment: без стиля все работает, вроде

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Используй либо событие PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, либо Click.

Вполне возможно, что тебе вообще в данном случае не нужна именно кнопка, можно всё, что я увидел в стиле сделать для другого более простого элемента, вроде ContentControl:

**App.xaml**

```
  <Style x:Key="SeriousStyle"
         TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static Brushes.Transparent}" />
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
              <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="#FF9E9E9E"
                      BorderThickness="1"
                      CornerRadius="1">
                 <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              </Border>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
     <Style.Triggers>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
           <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                 <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.6"
                                               RepeatBehavior="0:0:3"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0"
                                           Value="Lime" />
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.3"
                                           Value="Red" />
                 </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
           </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
  <ContentControl x:Name="btnFirst"
          Width="223"
          Height="79"
          Margin="27,189,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Content="{Binding Counter,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                           AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"
          MouseLeftButtonDown="AnswerWasChosen"
          Style="{DynamicResource SeriousStyle}" />
```

Можешь почитать о своей проблеме в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

*Дополнение к предыдущему ответу.*

Из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_8):

> Метод `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` помечает событие `MouseLeftButtonDown` как обработанное. Чтобы ответить на событие `MouseLeftButtonDown`, присоедините обработчик событий к событию `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` или вызовите метод `AddHandler(RoutedEvent, Delegate, Boolean)`, задав для параметра `handledEventsToo` значение `true`.

Таким образом, событие не должно доставляться, независимо от стиля. Используйте обходные пути, указанные в документации.

Comment: Но ведь он и так использует событие `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, что-то я не понимаю обоих ответов

Comment: @ixSci: Как я понял, ТС жалуется на то, что не отрабатывает `AnswerWasChosen`. Стиль по сути не участвует в проблеме.

Comment: понял, я просто смотрел на стиль и упорно не видел другого куска кода.